# Obstructions for a root of a given line bundle on a curve over arbitrary base field to exist

Tags: algebraic-geometry

## Vague question

Let $C$ be a proper smooth curve over a base field $k$, not necessarily algebraically closed but $\textrm{char}\, k \neq 2$. Let $N$ be a line bundle on $C$. If $L$ is a line bundle on $C$ such that $L^2 \simeq N$ then call $L$ a root of $N$.

My question is this:

> What are the obstructions for the existence of roots of $N$?

### Example

If $k=\mathbb{C}$ then given any line bundle $N$ of degree $d$ on $C$, there exists line bundles $L$ such that $L^2 \simeq N$ iff $d$ is even. So the only obstruction for the existence of a root is $d \, (\textrm{mod}\, 2)$.

This statement can easily be proven by considering the squaring map between equidimensional complex tori $\mathrm{Pic}^{\frac{d}{2}}(C) \to \mathrm{Pic}^{d}(C)$. It is easy to see that the fibers have to be finite (as they differ by 2-torsion), so the map is surjective.

### More specific question

Suppose $\textrm{deg}\, N$ is even. The situtation over $\mathbb{C}$ suggests that for arbitrary $k$, at least after a finite degree base change, a root of $N$ should exist. Then one could ask:

> If $N$ has no roots, what is the smallest degree field extension required for the existence of a root?

Comment: A crude estimate is that for a field extension of degree at most $2^{2g}$, $g$ being the genus of $C$, such a root can be found.

Comment: Fair enough =) However, I suspect the answer has to be 2 (at least , I'm pretty sure it is true over $\mathbb{C}((t))$) but I can't approach this problem in this generality.